# Problem with ethernet wired connection

Tags: ubuntu, ethernet

I have a problem with my wired ethernet connection on a Dell Inspiron 5593 with Ubuntu 20.04.
When I try to connect it keeps asking me for the password continuously. Wired connection work fine with windows operating system.

Running **lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 8a12 (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G7 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a03 (rev 03)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 34ef (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Management Engine Interface (rev 30)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 30)
00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2c Controller #4 (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 30)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 34b1 (rev 30)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 34b4 (rev 30)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a809
```

Running **ifconfig**:

```
enp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 98:e7:43:23:ee:98  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 428  bytes 88040 (88.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 124  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11  bytes 198 (198.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 11433  bytes 1017879 (1.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11433  bytes 1017879 (1.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.134  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        inet6 fe80::82e7:348:ff4f:ef24  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 40:23:43:c8:91:53  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2689989  bytes 3915552343 (3.9 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1395506  bytes 130709369 (130.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Running **nmcli device**:

```
*DEVICE          TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION   
wlp2s0          wifi      connected     Quick Hospot 
p2p-dev-wlp2s0  wifi-p2p  disconnected  --           
enp1s0          ethernet  unavailable   --           
lo              loopback  unmanaged     --
```

(when ethernet cable is plugged in, it shows "connecting" on enp1s0 state)

Running **route**:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
```

Running **dmesg**: https://pastebin.com/PG7yZdYw

I tried different solutions but nothing has worked.

Comment: Password for a wired connection? Are you sure you're not connecting to some Wi-Fi instead?

Comment: Yes, I have password for this wired connection, idk why the provider did this. But this isn't the problem, I connect with the password on windows with no problem.

Comment: Are you using PPPoE?

Comment: What "it" keeps asking you for a password? Assuming it's not a web browser introducing some captive portal (reachable via WiFi possibly - you haven't posted `ip a` nor `ip r` results) - isn't the network 802.1x protected?